# Replacement Segue Fails to Function...why?

Tags: segue, uistoryboard

**Problem:** 
Attempting to re-create a functioning segue fails.

**Scenario:** 
I'm attempting to create a drop-down menu using a UIContainerView connected to the hosting UIViewController via an 'embedded' segue; from which the member UIViewControllers are connected via a 'custom' segue.

I'm *trying* to get a firm grasp of how to work (create/re-create) with customized segues.

Here's what the result should look like:
[image]

Here's the list of segues:
[image]

This is the segue wiring that allows this to happen:
[image]

Each of these segues work with or w/out its identifier. 
 The following method is fired for *all functional* segues:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([self.currentSegueIdentifier isEqual:identifier]) {
        //Dont perform segue, if visible ViewController is already the destination ViewController
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

---

However, If I were to remove any of these segues, and try to re-establish a connection (via control-drag from origin to target) with all apparent attributes re-established, the new segue FAILS to fire.

That is, the above 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier()' DOES NOT FIRE.

**Question:** what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had made a control-drag from the origin UIViewController ---> destination UIViewController.   The attributes were set to be the EXACT values of the original segue.  Yet it failed to function.

Eventually I took notice of the button that was supposed to trigger the numbed segue.   I compared its link properties with the working others.  And that was the clue.

The solution was to link between the BUTTON & target UIViewController; NOT between the two UIViewControllers:

[image]